# Get authors who has posts in category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm using [Barcelona theme](http://themeforest.net/item/barcelona-clean-news-magazine-wordpress-theme/13308848) and I need to get authors who have posted in certain category.

In my author.php template I have:

```
$barcelona_authors = get_users( array(
    'fields' => 'ID',
    'who'    => 'authors',
    'order'  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'=> 'post_count'
) );

<?php
foreach ( $barcelona_authors as $barcelona_author_id ) { 
  barcelona_author_box( $barcelona_author_id, false );
}
?>
```

How to get authors who have posted to category ID 59?

For example I tried with:

```
$barcelona_authors = get_posts('category=59');
```

But I'm getting error. Any help?

ERROR:

> Notice: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to int in
>   /home/wp-includes/author-template.php on line 296

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution for [Barcelona theme](http://themeforest.net/item/barcelona-clean-news-magazine-wordpress-theme/13308848):

```
$barcelona_posts = get_posts('cat=59');
$barcelona_author_ids = array();

foreach ( $barcelona_posts as $k => $v ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $v->post_author, $barcelona_author_ids ) ) {
        $barcelona_author_ids[] = $v->post_author;
    }
}

$barcelona_authors = get_users( array(
    'fields' => 'ID',
    'who'    => 'authors',
    'order'  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'=> 'post_count',
    'include' => $barcelona_author_ids
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_posts( 'category=59' )` code should work. I have tested the following on one of my test wordpress installation and it works (with a different category ID of course). If you get an error during the `get_posts` call you need to show us the error.

```
<?php

    $category_posts = get_posts( 'category=59' );
    $authors_ids = array();
    $authors = array();

    foreach( $category_posts as $cat_post ) {
        $authors_ids[] = $cat_post->post_author;
    }

    // Not sure if you need more data than just the ID so here is what you need
    // to get other fields.

    foreach( $authors_ids as $id ) {
        $user = get_user_data( $id );
        // Display name: $user->display_name;
        // Nice name: $user->user_nicename;
        // etc...
    }

?>
```